# What is more important to an answerer: Accepted answer or reps?

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

What is more important to an answerer: Accepted answer or reps? A lot of times I get multiple good answers and it's hard to choose, so I pick one (fastest, first, most usable, nicest, I dunno) for the accepted answer, and then +1 the "runners-up" that I think deserve it and put in effort or something. Is this right?

Comment: The endorphins. I do it for the endorphins. *Give me more!* **Give me more!** ***Give me more, now!***

Comment: I do it [to make copies of my DNA](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/08/19.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Accept the answer that you consider best (that helped you most), and upvote all good answers. The reputation that comes with it is incidental, the point is to indicate good answers to the next visitors.